# STM32 get the privilege level

Tags: c, assembly, stm32

Is there a way to get the privilege level of execution and store it in variable?

I need it to avoid a hard fault that RTL-OS generates, whenever `os_sem_wait` is called from an IRQ. Potentially checking if any interrupt has occurred should also do the trick.

In addition it is important that the information about the privilege level will be available in privileged as well as unprivileged levels, or otherwise that may trigger the Hard Fault or another exception again.

The StdPeriph_Lib version is 3.5.0 for stm32f10x with RTL-OS.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you mention what OS you're using?

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](http://read.pudn.com/downloads112/sourcecode/middleware/469096/STM32F10xFWLib/FWLib/examples/CortexM3/Example2/main.c__.htm)

Comment: @FiddlingBits, STM32 is an embedded programming platform. There are a few OSes for these, but there are good chances that OP's not running any.

Comment: RTL-OS if that brings something

Comment: @LPs is __MSR_CONTROL available in unprivileged level?

Comment: The register access operation in MSR depends on the privilege level. Unprivileged software can only access the APSR, see Table 2.4. Privileged software can access all special registers.[LINK](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/CHDBIBGJ.html)

Comment: So it didn't worked out. The std 3.x version of __MSR_CONTROL is __get_BASEPRI and it has returned always 0x00000000 either in privileged or unprivileged levels. It appears that trying to access the CONTROL register in unprivileged level doesn't throw any exception, though the returned value is not meaningful. Still looking for the solution...

Comment: If the IPSR is non zero, the CPU is in handler mode and thus in privileged mode. If it's zero then the CPU is thread mode and may or may not be in privileged mode. If CONTROL.nPRIV is zero then thread mode is privileged, otherwise thread mode is unprivileged. If you're not using GCC I don't know how to access these registers in C. __MSR_CONTROL sounds like it would access the later. __get_BASEPRI would be something completely different.

Comment: @RossRidge http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00228916.pdf they are the same registers but under different STD_LIB versions.

Comment: You're reading the table wrong.  The CMSIS equivilent of the __MRS_CONTROL macro is __get_CONTROL.

Comment: @RossRidge you are right. I thought the gray shading is for STM32F10xxx FWLib V3.5.0. Thank you! It's solved now.

Comment: @zneak Assumed OS because OP is calling `os_sem_wait` from IRQ.